# fopen return NULL when passing first parameter with "*" character

Tags: c++, null, stream, fopen

I have to use fopen() function to create file and write something.But when i pass first parameter using "*" character; fopen() returns NULL always.

Example:

```
FILE *fp
const std::string sympath ="c:\\SysData/NonStandart/SUP*------*****.png"


fp = fopen(sympath.c_str(), "wb+");
```

fp returns NULL always.

I have to use "*" character. How can i fix this problem?

OS = windows 10 and Centos7

Comment: If your OS or file system forbids the character, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Do you try to use `*` as place-holder, or does your file name really contain these `*`s? This won't work in either case. There are no place-holders supported in `fopen()`, and `*` is (at least on Windows) a reserved character which shouldn't be used in file names. ([Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file#naming-conventions))

Comment: @Scheff It is NATO joint standard symbology SID code. Hmm i suppose, i have to replace '*' character with something else.

Comment: Do these military guys work with *ix systems exclusively? (In *ix systems `/` and `\0` are the only excluded characters - I just recalled.) I first thought you are joking but, out of curiosity, I googled and found [NATO Joint Military Symbology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_Joint_Military_Symbology) with e.g. `***` Platoon, etc. Centos: that's a Linux - hence, the `"c:\\"` probably won't work. On Windows, `*` is prohibited - how about replacing with `'\u2731'` (the unicode point for `✱`)? (Most people will probably not realize the difference.) ;-)

Comment: For Windows, see [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file), and in particular [Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions). Amongst several others, the `*` character is reserved and cannot be used in folder names or file names.